# How to determine if an element is visible in a Spark DataGrid Scroller viewport

Tags: flex4, flex4.5

How can I determine if a Spark DataGrid row, with specific data, is visible in the viewport of the Scroller that wraps the DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I was looking in the API Reference docs for the spark `spark.components.Grid`. The `Grid` offers a method `isCellVisible(rowIndex:int = -1, columnIndex:int = -1):Boolean`.

Since the `spark.components.Grid` represents the grid part of the `spark.components.DataGrid`, the method can be called as follows `dataGrid.grid.isCellVisible(rowIndex);`.

I call this method in an event listener to determine if a row (object) is visible in the scroller:

```
dataGrid.scroller.verticalScrollBar.addEventListener(TrackBaseEvent.THUMB_RELEASE,updateIsItemVisible);

private function updateIsItemVisible( e:Event):void
{
    var visible:Boolean = dataGrid.grid.isCellVisible( _itemIndex );
}
```